# Verificação Com Duas Tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Galera to tentando criar um sistema onde eu tenho duas tabelas uma chamada de `acompanhamentos` e a outra `produtos`.

Dentro da tabela acompanhamentos existe a coluna `sincroniza` onde eu gravo varios numeros separados por uma virgula, e esses numeros são relacionados a coluna id na tabela produtos.

Eu preciso fazer uma verificação que pega esse valor na coluna `sincroniza` e verifica entre as virgulas se existe um numero igual na tabela `produtos` se existir ele puxa o nome do produto e exibe o nome ao inves de exibir o numero.

Eu até agora não consegui fazer nada sobre isso, me falaram sobre uma tal de tabela pivot mas não faço nem ideia de como pelo menos começar isso, já que não conheço essa tabela pivot e sou novo com php e com o mysql

Comment: Amigo, a implementação feita por você está um pouco 'complexa'. Para fazer o que você está querendo será necessário um select nessa coluna sincroniza e então tratar esse valores fora do SQL, vai dar trabalho. O melhor que você pode fazer é: na tabela acompanhamentos você cria uma coluna que vai conter somente 1 ID da tabela produtos, depois um select usando INNER JOIN já resolve o que você quer.

Comment: Você pode conferir o conceito descrito por mim neste link http://goo.gl/ezrwLk

Comment: Nesse caso já que fica muito complexo tem como eu fazer com que cada id fique numa coluna diferente, tipo sincroniza1, sincroniza2, sincroniza3, sincroniza4 e asssim por diante, lembrando que cada vez que adicionar um novo id ele deve adicionar também uma nova coluna, tem como fazer assim?

Comment: Vou te dar um exemplo do que eu disse: http://pastebin.com/MBVxW7aQ

Comment: Esse exemplo seu é se for só um id né? ao invés de varios

Comment: Essa é a forma correta de implementar o que você quer.

Comment: isso vai funcionar se o campo prod_id na tabela acompanhamentos for do tipo varchar?

Comment: Uma busca por dados númericos é mais rápida do que uma busca por strings. O campo prod_id tem que ter o mesmo tipo de dado em ambas as tabelas, por se tratar de um ID (dado único) é aconselhável usar tipo inteiro. Não aconselho você a trocar o tipo de dado do prod_id

Comment: Mas mesmo sendo inteiro eu consigo por uma virgula nele? porque vai separar os números por virgula e na implementação de novos números eu iria usar, "UPDATE xxx SET sincroinza = CONCAT(sincroinza, ",", novo_número)"

Comment: Não consegue, pois ele é do tipo inteiro.

Comment: Tem como eu fazer da forma que eu te falei lá? ir criando varias colunas?, porque se tiver somente um numero, o sistema não funciona, o que eu preciso mesmo é que ele tenha varios numeros

Comment: Para fazer da forma que você disse você primeiro faz um select na tabela acompanhamentos, depois, com esses dados você pode usar a função explode() usando o delimitador ',' e então tratando o array e verificando 1 a 1 se é igual ao ID do produto que você tem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponha:

Produtos:

- 01 Açucar
- 02 Café
- 03 Agua
- 04 Batata

Acompanhamentos

- 02,01,03
- 02,03
- 03,01,04

**Solução**

Primeiro, você devera fazer uma consulta para retornar todos os dados de uma compra na tabela acompanhamentos.

Segundo, coloque um `while` para que enquanto houver "codigos" na `sincroniza`, a função continue sendo executada e os dados jogados em um `array`. Algo como:

```
$array=explode(",",$dados_da_sincroniza);
```

Terceiro, Faça uma nova consulta relacionando os dados do `array` criado acima com os `ids` da tabela produtos

Comment: Tem como explicar um pouco melhor eu não entendi a ideia do while, e quanto a consulta que você, é só fazer um select basico né?

Comment: @AlfredoLima O while é para que a função percorra todos os dados da coluna sincroniza no registro que vc deseja. Se executar sem ele, apenas o primeiro produto sera mostrado

Comment: @AlfredoLima O primeiro select sim. Apenas ele e a condição. Já o terceiro passo requer uma relação, que seria acompanhamentos.id=produtos.id

Comment: Tem como me dar um exemplo fazendo favor de como faço esse while?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função find_in_set do mysql para já retornar o resultado necessário, para não precisar percorrer em um foreach pelo php.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM acompanhamentos a
INNER JOIN produtos p
ON FIND_IN_SET(p.id,a.sincroniza)
```

e claro adicionando sua clausula where se necessário.